# Is possible make select in mysql which parse and search for letter?

Tags: mysql, select

I have in my sql database column with string. String looks like: "A,AC,ACC,ACA". Is possilble make select where string contains two times letter A between two commas?

So for example two rows with data:

A,AC,ACC,ACA,ACX

A,C,CC,CX,ACX,XCA

and select return only first row because there is part "ACA" so there are two letters A...

Comment: 1) What happens if there are 3xA in a word? 2) Can a word be longer than 3 letters? 3) Why don't you denormalise the data? 4) What have you done so far to solve your own problem?

Comment: 1. If there are 3xA in word row is not returned (does not meet the conditions), 2. yes words can be longer up to 6. 3. I can't i have only this data. 4. I was trying generate some combinations with 'like' but total wrong solution... I will try answer from @GurV

Comment: You should include what you have tried even if it does not work (describe what does not work) to show that you have actually tried something. Your question in its current format reads like a work request, which is not well received here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be storing the values in normalized form, not in CSV.

You can give this weird regular expression a try for now.

```
select * from t where concat(',', column, ',') regexp ',[^,]*A[^,]*A[^,]*,';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the % operator.

```
SELECT name FROM tb_table WHERE name LIKE '%A,A%A,A%';
```